# specify every combination of the features then calculate, extract, and store values

Tags: r

I have a classification variable and a few dozen ordinal features. I'd like to find the smallest subset of features that, when summed, produce the most accurate classification. I'm trying to specify every combination of the features, calculate a sum score for each combination, and then identify the best cutoff point to maximize sensitivity and specificity. Here's what I've tried:

```
library(gtools)
library(OptimalCutpoints)
set.seed(2)
# create fake data for 1 classification variable and just 5 features
  df <- data.frame(class=sample(0:1, 50, replace=T),
                   v01=sample(0:3, 50, replace=T),
                   v02=sample(0:3, 50, replace=T),
                   v03=sample(0:3, 50, replace=T),
                   v04=sample(0:3, 50, replace=T),
                   v05=sample(0:3, 50, replace=T))
# combinations
  vars <- list()
  out <- list()
  for (i in 2:(length(df)-1)) {
    p <- combinations(n = length(df)-1, r = i, v = names(df[2:(length(df))]))
    for (r in 1:nrow(p)) {
      keep <- c("class", p[r,])
      df_ <- df[, keep]
      df_$T <- rowSums(df_[,2:length(keep)])
      oc <- summary(optimal.cutpoints(X = "T", 
                              status = "class", 
                              tag.healthy = 0, 
                              methods = "SpEqualSe", 
                              data = df_, 
                              pop.prev = NULL, 
                              categorical.cov = NULL,
                              control = control.cutpoints(),
                              ci.fit = TRUE, 
                              conf.level = 0.95, 
                              trace = FALSE))
      name <- paste(i, r, sep=".")
      vars[[name]] <- append(vars, p[r,])
      out[[name]] <- append(out, oc) # when I inspect out R stalls
    }
  }
```

I don't think I'm going about this the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might (a) drive the anti-looping establishment crazy and (b) be super slow when the number of variables increases and the number of combinations goes through the roof, but I think it "works".

```
library(gtools)
library(OptimalCutpoints)
# create fake data
  df <- data.frame(class=sample(0:1, 50, replace=T),
                   v01=sample(0:3, 50, replace=T),
                   v02=sample(0:3, 50, replace=T),
                   v03=sample(0:3, 50, replace=T),
                   v04=sample(0:3, 50, replace=T),
                   v05=sample(0:3, 50, replace=T))
```

The basic idea is to loop through each combination of variable combinations, from sets of 2 through 5 variables. For each combination of variables, I calculate a scale score then determine the `optimal.cutpoints`. I extract the details of the `optimal.cutpoints` object and store in a dataframe that grows with each pass.

```
# combinations
  dfoc <- as.data.frame(NULL)
  ri <- 1
  for (i in 2:(length(df)-1)) {  
    p <- combinations(n = length(df)-1, r = i, v = names(df[2:(length(df))]))
    for (r in 1:nrow(p)) {
      keep <- c("class", p[r,])
      v <- keep[-1]
      df_ <- df[, keep]
      df_$T <- rowSums(df_[,2:length(keep)])
      oc <- summary(optimal.cutpoints(X = "T", 
                                      status = "class",
                                      tag.healthy = 0,
                                      methods = "SpEqualSe",
                                      data = df_,
                                      control = control.cutpoints(),
                                      ci.fit = TRUE,
                                      conf.level = 0.95, 
                                      trace = FALSE))
      dfoc[ri,1] <- i                                    # number vars in set
      dfoc[ri,2] <- r                                    # permutation number
      dfoc[ri,3] <- paste(v, collapse=",")               # var names in set
      dfoc[ri,4] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][1]     # cutoff
      dfoc[ri,5] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][2]     # sen
      dfoc[ri,6] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][3]     # spe
      dfoc[ri,7] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][4]     # ppv
      dfoc[ri,8] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][5]     # npv
      dfoc[ri,9] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][2,2]   # sen l95
      dfoc[ri,10] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][2,3]  # sen u95
      dfoc[ri,11] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][3,2]  # spe l95
      dfoc[ri,12] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][3,3]  # spe u95
      dfoc[ri,13] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][4,2]  # ppv l95
      dfoc[ri,14] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][4,3]  # ppv u95
      dfoc[ri,15] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][5,2]  # npv l95
      dfoc[ri,16] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][5,3]  # npv u95
      dfoc[ri,17] <- oc$p.table$Global$AUC_CI               # auc
      ri <- ri+1
      remove(df_)
      remove(keep)
      remove(v)
      remove(oc)
    }
  }
```